# SSH Secure Shell Tunnel X11 - Display not shown

Tags: security, shell, connection, x11, tunnel

I am using SSH Secure Shell to connect to a server. My connection is allowed to Tunnel X11 connections but when I execute the command. The display is not showing up. I get the message: 
couldn't connect to display "localhost:12.0"

I have a ssh server installed and running on my machine.

Comment: 1. Which command do you try to execute? 2. Try to run `ssh` with `-v` and look for any errors or warnings related to X11 port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember: Both the client and the server have to allow X forwarding.**

On the server look in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure you have `X11Forwarding yes`. You will need to restart the service if you edit this file.

On the client look in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (your user `~/.ssh/ssh/config` will override global settings, if you have created this file) and make sure you have `ForwardX11 yes`.

Alternatively give the `-X` switch when you create your client connection. e.g. `ssh -X user@host`

Oh and of course, your client needs to be running an X server which you have authority to use! E.g. if you connect from Windows using PuTTY it will never work, as Windows is not an X server!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to have X-Server installed on my computer instead of SSH-Server. I installed Xming for that purpose and now everything works as it should.